# rails routing not going to controller as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I would like to get reviews for a specific user. I'm trying to hit

```
var reviews_url = '/users/' + profile_id + '/reviews.json';
```

but it's not hitting `reviews#index` as seen in the logs

```
Started GET "/users/23/reviews.json" for ::1 at 2015-05-03 10:50:01 -0700
Processing by ApplicationController#index as JSON
```

What can I change to make this route hit `reviews#index`?

`routes.rb`

```
resources :users do
    resources :reviews
end
```

`rake routes`

```
GET    /users/:user_id/reviews(.:format)              reviews#index
```

EDIT TO ADD ROUTES

```
get 'auth/:provider/callback', to: 'sessions#create'
root 'application#index'
get '*path' => 'application#index'
resources :users do
    resources :reviews
    resources :friendships
end
```

Note: when I move `resources` above `get '*path' => 'application#index'` it works as expected. However I would like to have each call go through `application#index` (the app is a SPA that knows the current user based on the user in `application#index`). Maybe I should namespace these routes into `api`?

Comment: Routes look correct... what do your `ApplicationController` and `ReviewsController` look like.  Are you doing authentication or authorization that might be tripping it up?

Comment: Thats really strange. Can you post your whole routes file? The only thing I can think of is that there is not index action defined in your reviews controller.  Is there an index method in your application controller (seems weird).

Comment: @jphager2 in that case it should complain about the missing action.

Comment: @nafaa not if it's defined in the application controller (assuming that ReportsController < ApplicatonController)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so you need to think about it differently.

Routes only match to one action.  So if you want to have certain code executed on specific requests, you can't do it by appling a catch all route.

So first, remove `get '*path' => "application#index"` from `routes.rb`

Then in `application_controller.rb` add a before_action:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :do_this_before_all_actions

  # ...
  private
  def do_this_before_all_actions
    # the code you want to run
   end
end
```

Thus every controller that inherits from ApplicationController will have this code executed first.